# How to use obfuscated Jquery script in Asp.NET MVC3?

Tags: jquery

For Example If I want to obfuscate my code

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").click(function(event){
     alert("Thanks for visiting!");
   });
 });
</script>
```

After obfuscating in jsobfuscate.com I get the Following code

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('$(4).3(0(){$("2").1(0(5){8("7 6 9!")})});',10,10,'function|click|a|ready|document|event|for|Thanks|alert|visiting'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

If i place this obfuscated code inside script tag its not working Is there any other reference that I should I have to Add for obfuscated jquery.

Comment: This is going to sound dumb, but did you put a semicolon after it?

Comment: @AnnL. yes Semicolon was not added in this question but I have it in my code. I am Asking the procedure of obfuscation. can we simply add obfuscated jquery code inside script tag

Comment: What errors are you seeing in your javascript console? What browser are you using? All helpful in helping to get down to the bottom of this.

Comment: You *are* linking to jQuery before adding the obfuscated code, right?

Comment: This question has no relation to asp.net mvc. I removed the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to obsfuscate it?

Apart from making the code longer and probably more brittle, the code should be pretty easy to reverse engineer.

It's a pretty pointless exercise...

Comment: Seriously??? There's enough good jQuery examples around and I don't think most people bother looking at others js (it's only us really nerdy people)

Comment: Whoa!! cool i dont meant to fight. i know that. because im a student I have some stupid friends working on the same project So I need to hide my code from those noobs.

Comment: please can you teach me the procedure of obfuscation of jquery in ASP.NET mvc3

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscating your code like that seems useless, and will increase the file size (bad for the users). Your code can be unobfuscated easily with tools like http://jsbeautifier.org/. Why not just minifying? Your code, minified, would be simply this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("a").click(function(a){alert("Thanks for visiting!")})})
```

Comment: I want to learn how obfuscation works. please can you teach me the procedure of obfuscation of jquery in ASP.NET mvc3

Comment: Sorry, I can't. I don't think JS code should be obfuscated, so I never tried it.